# Add APP scope to existing Google Place

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

When I add a place via the Web Service API, that place will immediately be assigned a Place ID with a scope of APP. I then add that Place ID along with the app-specific data to my DB. If I were to do a Nearby Search I imagine I would filter the results returned from the Web Service API to only include Places with a scope of APP and then proceed to search my DB for the filtered Place IDs.

If the Place already exists on Google, should I re-create it? In doing so will mean I am returned a Place with a scope of APP. It will be rejected by Google during their moderation process, so will not be publicly visible as it is a duplicate, however will always be visible to the app, or is there a method for adding an APP scope to an existing Google Place?

**tl;dr** Is there a method for adding an APP scope to an existing Google Place or is duplicating an existing Place just to have an APP scope a reasonable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Any Place currently on the public Google map has a scope as *GOOGLE*. That place has been already gone through the moderation process and has been made public with a specific ID. You can add the same place with the scope as APP, Google shall allot a separate ID to that place and it will be only specific to your app and not public. It wont complain as duplicate Place, its just that it will be recognized by your application only.